# External program in PHP

Tags: php, process, youtube, exec, wget

I'm trying to make a simple script in PHP which download a video of youtube, at the first moment I tried some classes I found on web but unsuccessful, so I decide to use youtube-dl program and call it from to my script.

The big problem is: apparently the process is killed when the page loads in the browser and the download is interrupted.

The most curious thing is that if I execute the script like that: *php page.php*, the script works nicely but the browser doesn't work.

I note the same thing with wget command, the process also killed.

The code is something like:

```
<?php
  exec("youtube-dl -o /var/www/YT/video.flv https://youtube....");
?>
```

and

```
<?php
  exec("wget http://link");
?>
```

*Both youtube-dl and wget are in the same directory from script, I tried too redirect output to /dev/null and fork process mas both no success.

Comment: Does your webserver user have sufficient rights to write to a file in /var/www/YT/? By the way, you do realize that you might be breaking the copyright of the files you're downloading?

Comment: Did you `chmod 775 /var/www/YT/` already?

Comment: I'm embarassed now, for tests I set 777 permission for the folder and worked perfectly, very very thanks.

Comment: Don't know if the /var/www/YT/ directory is on a production environment, but setting it there to 0777 is a real security threat. Better to change the owner to the webserver user.

Answer (score 0):

I would try executing it at the background.

```
<?php
  exec("youtube-dl -o /var/www/YT/video.flv https://youtube....  > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
?>
```

If that works then what it's happening is that your php script ends before youtube-dl

Comment: You're suggesting that the executed program takes too long and PHP times out. That should not be a problem, as the time needed to execute the program is not counted towards the execution time limit; only the time needed to actual execute the PHP code is measured for that goal. So the youtube-dl program may take as long as it wants and the PHP script will still run. See http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: Thanks Serpes, the problem was not exactly that (as I said in the comment above) but the script was of great help.